# model relations and bulk deletes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

I have a model relation of dependant=>destroy that has to do 50K+ deletes when the destroy is triggered. Looking at the console, rails is trying to do an explicit delete with ID for every single row, which is taking a while. Is there a way for me to force rails to do a bulk delete? Or, I can remove the model dependency, is there a way to do this kind of bulk delete from the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set dependent: delete_all

If you can't get that to work, you might want to use delete_all in your own callback.

To be clear, delete_all should generate a single statement to delete all child objects